# How to set focus on the ace editor?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, ace-editor

I am using the ace editor component from ajax.org inside a jquery tab interface.
Each tab will contain a separate ace editor. Whenever I switch to a new tab, the editor in it won't get the focus.

I can detect when a tab is selected by binding to the "tabsshow" event of jquery UI. Does any one know how to set focus to the editor in it if say the id of my editor div is editor-tab-0
 for the first tab, and so on...?

Please can some one help?

Comment: Do you had a look at the "Ace Kitchen Sink"? http://ace.ajax.org/build/kitchen-sink.html There the hierarchy of components to the editor window is: `div#editor div.ace_editor div.ace_sb`. This should be the component that should get the focus.

Answer (score 39):

```
editor.focus(); //To focus the ace editor
var n = editor.getSession().getValue().split("\n").length; // To count total no. of lines
editor.gotoLine(n); //Go to end of document
```

Comment: Missing pieces: `<div id="aceEditor">` `var editor = ace.edit("aceEditor");`

Comment: helpful, but should be `editor.gotoLine(n, Infinity);` if you want to move the cursor to the end of the last line instead of the start of the last line.

Answer (score 23):

To focus to the end:

```
editor.focus();
editor.navigateFileEnd();
```

Thanks to @a-user

Answer (score 12):

Nice solution, but I wanted to go to the end of the last line not the beginning of the last line.

```
//To focus the ace editor
editor.focus();
session = editor.getSession();
//Get the number of lines
count = session.getLength();
//Go to end of the last line
editor.gotoLine(count, session.getLine(count-1).length);
```

Answer (score 4):

Here's an excerpt from my code that sets the focus on an Ace edit session in a jQuery UI tab:

```
    $('#tabs_div').tabs(
        {
            select : function(event, ui) {
                        var tabName = ui.panel.id;
                        var doc = docs.get(tabName);  // look up the EditSession
                        var session = env.split.setSession(doc);
                        session.name = tabName;
                        env.editor.focus();
            }
```

Comment: I'd like to give +1 for the answer if you explained what are those variables in the `select` function, because pasting the snippet as is doesn't work.

Comment: @Rajish The context is a jQuery UI Tab - see http://jqueryui.com/demos/tabs/. The env variable is set up in the Ace kitchen sink example.

Answer (score 0):

I use JQuery with the Ace Editor, and I found the following code worked really nicely for me. PS: My Code Editor Window is in an Iframe:

```
$('#modelFrame').mouseover(function() {
    try {
        $(this).get(0).contentWindow.editor.focus();
    } catch (doNothing) {
        ;;
    }
});
```