# how to delete the content of ace editor on a validation error

Tags: ace-editor

My question is related to [set focus on ace editor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22459162/set-focus-on-ace-editor)

This time I want to delete the content whenever there is a validation error.

I have the used the pattern like

```
/^[0-4]$/ and /^([1-9][0-9]{0,3}|[1-5][0-9]{4}|60000)$/;
```

to check the value between 0-4 and 1-60000 respectively. When user provides invalid data my text area is cleared but not the ace editor. I also tried

```
    $scope.close = function () {
rowObj.entity.value = editor.getValue();
            editor.setValue("",0);
                };
```

but that is not working.

Comment: Why don't you just do an `editer.setValue("",0)`?

Comment: but I need to delete the content in case if there is a validation error in the textarea, how to do that, is there any event occurs during validation error which I can use to delete the content of ace editor

Comment: I modify the code but still not working, I don't know how to sync the state of textarea with the ace editor, is there any event

Comment: when I am using my solution(as described above) m not able to clear the editor. but when I am doing the reverse `editor.setValue("",0); rowObj.entity.value = editor.getValue();` I am able to do so. Actually I am checking certain condition before executing the second solution. I just want to know what is the impact of validation error message(the message displayed when a value is not allowed in a particular field) in angularjs. Is there any exception or error occurs or it is just cosmatic @JoseM

Answer (score 8):

to clear editor simply call `editor.setValue("")`